# Evaluate deep rooted key without nil pointer

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

I have a fairly complex values file, which is complex by design really. A single place to store common config for a number of deployments.

As a result, I need to use a lot of nested values like.

```
app1:
  environment:
    staging:
      replicas: 3
```

Which I select with:

```
{{ index .Values (.Values.app) "environment" (.Values.env) "replicas" }}
```

This works fine when the values exist.. but I'm looking to put a default in incase it does not and thus I need to be able to evaluate this at every iteration of the tree..

I've tried the obvious combinations, but of course it doesn't work with the likes of;

```
{{ if index .Values (.Values.app) "environment" (.Values.env) "replicas" }}
replicas: {{ index .Values (.Values.app) "environment" (.Values.env) "replicas" }}
{{ else }}
replicas: 1
{{ end }}
```

I saw another post on here which talks about the double parenthesis inherited from text/template, but I can't get that to work at all.

For bonus points, can anyone tell me how I can get the built in `default` function to work with `index`? I can't seem to get that to work either. I also wonder if theres a better way to handle the multiple (.Values.app) and (.Values.env)?

**EDIT:**

I've been experimenting with using `default` to add an empty dict to each step... but still no closer.. this is what I've currently been trying:

```
{{- $app := index .Values (.Values.appName) -}}
{{- $env := index $app "environment" | default dict -}}
{{- $replicas := index $env (.Values.env) | default dict -}}
{{- if $replicas "replicas" -}}
replicas: {{ index .Values (.Values.appName) "environment" (.Values.env) "replicas" }}
{{- else -}}
replicas: 1
{{- end -}}
```

**EDIT AGAIN:**

I'm slowly realising that it's just not possible to do what I'm trying to do in the way I'm trying to do it.. whichever way I think about it, it's going to be a bit messy.

Currently experimenting with this idea (although not yet working)..

```
{{- if hasKey index .Values (.Values.appName) "environment" -}}
{{- if hasKey index .Values (.Values.appName) "environment" (.Values.env) -}}
replicas: {{ index .Values (.Values.appName) "environment" (.Values.env) "replicas" }}
{{- end -}}
{{- else -}}
replicas: 1
{{- end -}}
```

My thinking is to evaluate each step with `hasKey` and proceed only if the previous key exists. But `hasKey` does not like `index` because it only wants 2 arguments passed to it. I've tried with a various selection of `()` to no avail.

**EDIT AGAIN, AGAIN:**

Feels like I'm nearly there.. not getting nil pointer error now.. but also, not getting `replicas` at all in the rendered manifest :(

```
{{ $app := index .Values (.Values.appName) }}
{{ if hasKey $app "environment" }}
{{ $env := index $app "environment" (.Values.env) }}
{{ if hasKey $env "replicas" and not empty $env "replicas" }}
{{ $replicas := index .Values (.Values.appName) "environment" (.Values.env) "replicas" }}
replicas: {{ default "1" $replicas  }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

EDIT AGAIN, AGAIN, AGAIN:

I see it!! We're not matching `{{ if hasKey $env "replicas" and not empty $env "replicas" }}` and thus replicas doesn't make it into the manifest at all. The behaviour I'm seeing makes sense, which means it should be easier to debug..

Comment: Please provide clearer corresponding values.yaml、template and expected output

Comment: What is unclear? I can elaborate specifically if helpful? The values snippet is there, and the templating is pretty evident in suggesting what I want the outcome to be. If that values block exists, take the replica count from it, if not default to a replica count of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a bit long winded, and not the nicest of solutions.. but this one puzzled me for quite a while! This is working as intended.. I'd still like to assemble a more elegant solution, but posting as an answer in case it helps other people.

```
{{ $app := index .Values (.Values.appName) }}
{{ if hasKey $app "environment" }}
{{ $env := index $app "environment" (.Values.env) }}
{{ if hasKey $env "replicas" and not empty $env "replicas" }}
{{ $replicas := index .Values (.Values.appName) "environment" (.Values.env) "replicas" }}
replicas: {{ $replicas  }}
{{ end }}
{{ else }}
replicas: 1
{{ end }}
```